# Angular 4 TalwindCSS setup

Tags: css, angular, configure, tailwind-css

Is there a way to configure [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com) with Angular (4+)?

I'm happy to eject the Angular project, to make webpack configuration available. But I'm not sure what to put in the `webpack.config.js` so that TailwindCSS works nicely with the internals of Angular.

It would be great to have a setup such that I can still use a single command for dev (something like `npm start`), and continue to file changes watched (including CSS). Same for building the project.

Comment: I made the tutorial here if you guys want to take a look. It is proven working with AOT and latest Angular 9, also compatible with the previous version as well. You will need `@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss` plugin to remove unused CSS class from Tailwind. If you don't include that plugin, it will result in a massive bundle size of CSS.

https://github.com/trungk18/angular-tailwind-css-configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1: (using ng-eject)**

You can find full steps in [this great video by Tom Gobich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUS0gclgO9Q) which I'd resume as follow:

1. [Bring Sass into your project](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli). If starting from scratch just run:

   ```
   $ ng new project --style=scss
   ```
2. Go inside project, [install tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#npm) then [generate the config file](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#2-create-a-tailwind-config-file):

   ```
   $ cd project
   $ npm install tailwindcss --save-dev 
   $ ./node_modules/.bin/tailwind init tailwind.config.js
   ```
3. [Eject your app](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/eject.md) to output the webpack configuration file and solve new dependencies:

   ```
   $ ng eject
   $ npm install
   ```
4. add the [tailwindcss plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#webpack) to **webpack.config.js** file:

   ```
   const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss'); // <-- create this constant
   ...

   const postcssPlugins = function () {
      ...
      return [
         postcssUrl({
           ...
         }),
         tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'), //<-- then add it here
         autoprefixer(),
         ...
    };
   ```
5. add the [@tailwind directives](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#3-use-tailwind-in-your-css) to **src/styles.scss**:

   ```
   @tailwind preflight;

   // your custom components goes here.

   @tailwind utilities;

   // your custom utilities goes here.
   ```
6. Start creating your tailwind components or grab [some sample code online](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/examples/cards/) and put it into **src/app/app.component.html** for quick tests then run:

   ```
   $ npm start
   ```

---

**Method 2: (without ng-eject)**

As mentioned in [this nice article](https://dev.to/iamafro/getting-started-with-tailwindcss-in-your-angular-project-bc3) by @hackafro (**Richard Umoffia**) you can also use Tailwind's CLI [to process your stylesheet](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#4-process-your-css-with-tailwind). To do so, after creating your app and generating tailwind's config file:

```
$ ng new project
$ cd project
$ npm install tailwindcss --save-dev 
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tailwind init tailwind.config.js
```

Create a new file at the same level of `styles.css`, call it `tailwind-build.css` for example, and add the following content to it:

```
@tailwind preflight;

// your custom components goes here.

@tailwind utilities;

// your custom utilities goes here.
```

Then, inside your **package.json** file add those 2 scripts under the `script` attribute:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "tailwind": "./node_modules/.bin/tailwind build ./src/tailwind-build.css -c ./tailwind.config.js -o ./src/styles.css",
    "prestart": "npm run tailwind" // or "yarn run tailwind" depending on which you are using
  }
},
```

Now every time you start your server, or every time you manually type in terminal:

```
npm run tailwind // or "yarn run tailwind"
```

Tailwind's CLI will be used to fill `./src/styles.css` content for you, which should work fine as angular CLI is already applying postCSS plugins on top of it including autoprefixer, more about it here: [This is how angular-cli/webpack delivers your CSS styles to the client](https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975)

Comment: As noted by ThanapongP., I get an "atRule.before..." error.

Comment: I made this the chosen answer, as using the latest angular version (from angular cli 1.6.0)  produces the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I put together some JavaScript using chokidar to watch my tailwind files and build them out when changes occur in my tailwind files, since Angular (as of 6.0.3, to the best of my knowledge) does not allow access to the postcss plugins in a CLI project (which is totally the way to go, in my humble opinion).

chokidar.js (top-level file, right next to package.json):

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar')
const child = require('child_process')

const tailwind = chokidar.watch(['tailwind.js', './src/tailwind.css'])

tailwind.on('change', (event, path) => {
  child.exec('npm run build-tailwind')
  console.log('Reprocessing Tailwind Files')
})
```

package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "build-tailwind": "./node_modules/.bin/tailwind build ./src/tailwind.css -c ./tailwind.js -o ./src/styles.css",
  "prestart": "npm run build-tailwind",
  "start": "ng serve & node chokidar.js",
  "build": "npm run prestart && ng build"
}
```

As you can see from the build-tailwind script, I just put `tailwind.css` in the `src/` folder with the global `styles.css`, and all of my custom css goes there like any other tailwind project.

tailwind.css:

```
@tailwind preflight;

/* custom components */

@tailwind utilities;

/* custom utilities */
```

I hope that helps somebody while we wait for Angular to give us access to post-css directly.

**UPDATE:**

I built a cli tool for npm, to make this super easy on anyone else trying to take advantage of what tailwind offers in their angular projects.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-tailwindcss

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way without having to eject the CLI and not having a specific npm script for tailwind but simply by hooking into your CLI's webpack loaders.

You need to install `npm install -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack postcss-scss tailwindcss`

Then create a `webpack.config.js` config file:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          syntax: 'postcss-scss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then change your `angular.json` file to use this new configuration:

```
...
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
  "options": {
    "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "webpack.config.js"
    },
    ...
  }
},
...
```

Import the tailwind utilities in your `styles.scss`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And now just run `npm start` and you are ready to use tailwind classes in your HTML or the @apply in your SCSS files!

Hope this helps.

I created a post to explain how in detail - https://medium.com/@joao.a.edmundo/angular-cli-tailwindcss-purgecss-2853ef422c02

Answer (score 0):

If someone follow Salem's answer above and have the **"atRule.before is not a function"** error, just update all PostCSS dependencies to the latest version and everything should be working again.

Comment: @HackAfro What I did was delete the node_modules folder and then delete all the postcss stuff in package.json. After that I use `npm install postcss --save-dev`, `npm install postcss-loader --save-dev` and `npm install postcss-url --save-dev` to install the latest version of those dependencies.

Comment: I installed the latest postcss, and the error goes away. Running npm start (effectively 'webpack-dev-server --port=4200'), serves the application. However the tailwind styles do not seem to be coming through to the components.

Comment: I tried again, with the latest angular version (angular cli 1.6.0) and it produces the desired result